# Full screen touch application hangs when a user touches the lower edge

Tags: wpf, windows, touchscreen

I am working on a wpf touchscreen application for a tabletop monitor.  The monitor is a 46" 3M monitor.  All the touch responses seem to work fine until someone touches the lower edge of the screen, then it appears to hang.  No button responses or drag options work until the finger or hand is moved.  I think it has something to do with the touch being in the region of the taskbar even though the taskbar itself does not appear.

The program does not hang if the user touches the side or top in the same way or even if they place their entire hand in the middle of the screen.

Since this is a tabletop monitor, it is very common for a user to lean on the monitor and unknowingly touch the lower edge with their hand.

Comment: Do you have an `Touch` event handlers attached?

Comment: Yes, the touch events are handled correctly when the lower edge of the screen is not covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug related to Windows 7 and multitouch drivers for Windows 7.  I can reliably reproduce this bug with Windows 7 with a multitouch display and a bezel flat enough to have touch contact on the lower edge.

Using the same program and multitouch display with Windows 8, the problem does not occur.

Comment: At a guess, this gives input capture to a different window (perhaps a minimized taskbar).  Do you still have the problem if your kiosk application uses `SetCapture` ?